# Latest Google Adwords oAuth API implementation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, google-oauth, google-ads-api

Good Day,

I am having issue trying to migrate my adwords API oAuth to the more recent API version which is v201705.

My old implementation using v201609 is working, and now since this version has been in the sunset. I have been migrating my app to the more recent API version.

Basically I am having a hard time trying to find any documentation from Google or anywhere that shows how to implement Google oAuth with the Adwords API that is relevant to the latest Adwords API versions.

Below is my current code:

```
$redirectUri = 'http://xxxxxxx/dashboard/accounts/oauth2callback';
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    //$code = Request::query('code');

    $user = new AdWordsUser(
                            base_path('auth.ini'),
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            base_path('settings.ini'),
                            null
                            );

    $OAuth2Handler = $user->GetOAuth2Handler();

    // Get the access token using the authorization code. Ensure you use the same
    // redirect URL used when requesting authorization.
    $user->SetOAuth2Info(
    $OAuth2Handler->GetAccessToken(
    $user->GetOAuth2Info(), $code, $redirectUri));

    // The access token expires but the refresh token obtained for offline use
    // doesn't, and should be stored for later use.
    //return $user->GetOAuth2Info();
    //$result = json_decode($user->GetOAuth2Info());

    $refreshToken = $user->GetOAuth2Info()['refresh_token'];
```

Can anyone point me to the correct implementation for the latest Google Adwords API version of this?

Below is what I have been trying to achieve at the moment, but obviously this is not working and/or missing something entirely:

```
$redirectUri = 'http://xxxxxxx/dashboard/accounts/oauth2callback';
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    //$code = Request::query('code');

    /* $user = new AdWordsUser(
                            base_path('auth.ini'),
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            base_path('settings.ini'),
                            null
                            ); */

    // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential for authentication.
    $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
        ->fromFile()
        ->build();

    // Construct an API session configured from a properties file and the OAuth2
    // credentials above.

    $user = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
    ->fromFile()
    ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
    ->build();

    $OAuth2Handler = $user->GetOAuth2Handler();

    // Get the access token using the authorization code. Ensure you use the same
    // redirect URL used when requesting authorization.
    $user->SetOAuth2Info(
    $OAuth2Handler->GetAccessToken(
    $user->GetOAuth2Info(), $code, $redirectUri));

    // The access token expires but the refresh token obtained for offline use
    // doesn't, and should be stored for later use.
    //return $user->GetOAuth2Info();
    //$result = json_decode($user->GetOAuth2Info());

    $refreshToken = $user->GetOAuth2Info()['refresh_token'];

    $customer_id = $this->GetClientCustomerName($refreshToken)['customer_id'];
    //$customer_name = $this->GetClientCustomerName($refreshToken)['customer_name'];
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have managed to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've finally figured out that I need to follow the Google OAuth2 implementation as I was using the Google Adwords implementation prior. Didn't knew that both would work the same.

Below is what I have come up and is now working:

```
$redirectUri = 'http://xxxxxxx/dashboard/accounts/oauth2callback';
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    $oauth2 = new OAuth2([
        'authorizationUri' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
        'tokenCredentialUri' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
        'redirectUri' => $redirectUri,
        'clientId' => $this->client_id,
        'clientSecret' => $this->client_secret,
        'scope' => '****'
    ]);


    $oauth2->setCode($code);
    $authToken = $oauth2->fetchAuthToken();

    // Store the refresh token for your user in your local storage if you
    // requested offline access.
    $refreshToken = $authToken['refresh_token'];
```